# Why is True being hit but not being returned to the main func

Tags: python, search, cpu-word, backtracking

Why is True not being returned to the "exist" main func when the first if statement in dfs is being hit? I'm sure I'm just missing something simple.

Leetcode question: https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-medium/109/backtracking/797/

```
class Solution:
    def exist(self, board: List[List[str]], word: str) -> bool:
        
        def dfs(x=0, y=0, found=0, seen = set()):
            if found == len(word):
                return True

            elif x < len(board) and y < len(board[0]) and board[x][y] == word[found]:
                if x > 0 and (x,y) not in seen:
                    seen.add((x,y))
                    dfs(x-1,y,found+1, seen.copy())
                    seen.remove((x,y))
                if x < len(board) and (x,y) not in seen:
                    seen.add((x,y))
                    dfs(x+1,y,found+1, seen.copy())
                    seen.remove((x,y))
                if y > 0 and (x,y) not in seen:
                    seen.add((x,y))
                    dfs(x,y-1,found+1, seen.copy())
                    seen.remove((x,y))
                if y < len(board[0]) and (x,y) not in seen:
                    seen.add((x,y))
                    dfs(x,y+1,found+1, seen.copy())
                    seen.remove((x,y))


        return dfs()
```

Comment: You need to save the value of the recursive calls in a variable and then return it.

Comment: you don't return any value in your recursive step

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong. Why do you hhve two nested functions in the class? Can you reduce this to a [mre]?